# Minimum time inpainting a polygon with constraints

Tags: algorithms, optimization, polygons

Given are the coordinates of a convex polygonal area ("field"), a moving circle of radius r ("crayon") and a home location for the crayon ("home") well outside the field.

**Main goal**: Get the shortest total end-to-end path of the crayon so the crayon fills most of the area of the field, without painting at all outside it. Overpainting is very discouraged.

The crayon has fixed speed.

**Constraints**

- The crayon's home, its starting and end point, is well outside the field.
- The crayon has a limited time of flight per leg. It has to return to home before the flight time is over to reset it. These back and forth flight times should be also considered in the total flight time minimization.

I think it may be a flavor of The Travelling Salesman, not sure.

Thank you!